# Designing Two Models to Have A Complex Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, associations, rails-activerecord

I have two tables, `users` and `groups`. An user owns a group and can be apart of multiple groups. A group belongs to one user and can have many users.

Thus for my `user` model I have

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
has_many :groups
```

While for my `group` model I have

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
belongs_to :user
```

I also have a join table in my migrations..

```
def change
  create_table :groups_users, :id => false do |t|
    t.integer :group_id
    t.integer :user_id
  end
end
```

My question is does this make sense? I feel like I'm doing something wrong by having `has_many` and `belongs_to` on top of `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Comment: `has_many :groups` and `belongs_to :user` not required

Comment: How will I differentiate between the user who owns the group and the group members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would approach this, and this is my own personal methodology, is with 3 tables/models like so:

**group_user.rb**

```
class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id, :group_id

  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**group.rb**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :owner_id

  validates_presence_of :owner_id

  has_many :group_users
  has_many :users, through: :group_users
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :some_attributes

  has_many :group_users
  has_many :groups, through: :group_users
end
```

Then, whenever you create a `Group` object, the `User` that created it would have its `id` placed in the `owner_id` attribute of `Group` and itself into the `GroupUser` table.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, so as to not have multiple foreign keys pointing to the same relationship, is to use a join model and then add a flag on the join model to denote if the user is the owner.

For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
  has_many :owned_groups, through: memberships, conditions: ["memberships.owner = ?", true], class_name: "Group"
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  #This model contains a boolean field called owner
  #You would create a unique constraint on owner, group and user
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  has_one :owner, through: :memberships, conditions: ["memberships.owner = ?", true], class_name: "User"
end
```

Comment: Since you were the first to post, I'll give you credit. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that Leo Correa answered first.

Comment: Ahh that he did. I'll change the answers then.